# React native packager: how to have both platform and retina suffix

Tags: react-native

As explained [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images) the react native packager works well for images with retina suffix (`@2x` and `@3x`) and platform specific suffix (`.android.png`, `.ios.png` etc.) when used individually but it fails to serve retina images when both are used at once. I tried mixing them both ways both `image@2x.android.png` and `image.android@2x.png` but only `1x` image is loaded on all devices regardless of device's pixel density. I'm importing image like `import image from './images/image.png'`. I tried searching for this on Google and in the `react-native` issues but couldn't find any helpful info.

Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong? If it's a bug then is there a workaround? If I'm doing something wrong then what's is it? I do not want the ios specific images to be bundled in android and vice-versa.